# Opening fancybox with boxslider for second time doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2, bxslider

So I've setup a fancybox with boxslider.
I have some problems with the boxslider when opening the fancybox again after closing it the first time.

[website](http://beanijdam.nl/site/portfolio.html) (please note that the onclick is only applied to the first block (top row, most left))

The fancybox is called by the code below:

```
<div class="img-spacer" onclick="$.fancybox({href : '#portfolio-1', width: 1040, margin: 0, padding: 0, closeBtn: false}); $('.bxslider').bxSlider({auto: true,controls: false,pager: false});">
```

This code works just fine when opening the fancybox for the first time but when I close the fancybox and open it again the boxslider is not working anymore like it is supposed to. It will skip some photo's and won't slide smoothly.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Every time you click on the image, a new instance of fancybox is created. So when you've clicked 2+ times, both fancybox instances try to move the image, and you get the mess you're seeing. What you need to do is stop/destroy fancybox when closing the window.

Comment: I suppose you mean something like forced closing the fancybox (as I don't see a stop or destroy function in the documentation). I tried to force the fancybox to close by using $.fancybox.close(true); but this didn't make a difference.

Comment: I do, I'll post an answer shortly with what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

Like I mentioned in my comment, you need to move the fancybox init out of the inline click handler, in into your JS file.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach fancybox to every .image-spacer div
    $("img-spacer").fancybox({
        href : '#portfolio-1', 
        width: 1040, 
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        closeBtn: false,
        onUpdate: function() {
            alert('update!');
        },
        onCancel: function() {
            alert('cancel!');
        },
        onPlayStart: function() {
            alert('play start!');
        },
        onPlayEnd: function() {
            alert('play end!');
        },
        beforeClose: function() {
            alert('before close!');
        },
        afterClose: function() {
            alert('after close!');
        },
        beforeShow: function() {
            alert('before show!');
        },
        afterShow: function() {
            alert('after show!');
        },
        beforeLoad: function() {
            alert('before load!');
        },
        afterLoad: function() {
            alert('after load!');
        }
    });

    // On clicking a .img-spacer div, attach a bxSlider
    $(".portfolio").click(function(){
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            auto: true,
            controls: false,
            pager: false
        });
    });
});
```

And for the HTML

```
<div class="img-spacer"></div>
```

Give this a shot and let me know how it went. If you place it on the live site I can take a look at it there.

Comment: I've tried this but when I open the fancybox for the second time it will not show pictures anymore. It just shows a blank space. I've uploaded it so you can see it yourself.

Comment: I see, could you update the website code with my updated code so I can see what gets called and when?

Comment: Done. Sidenote; you're missing a . in the first $("img-spacer")

Comment: Sorry man, I can't seem to find what's causing the issue. My last guess would be to remove any manual calls to $.fancybox.close